# rendering a webpage WITHOUT using the webbrowser control in .net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest

I've pulled down a webpage using a WebRequest object, and need to parse it, but first I need to render it since there is scripting on the page. I don't want to use the WebBrowser control because that forces me to jump out of my current function to the DocumentCompleted event, and "lose my place" (so to speak). Is there any way for me to pull down a URL using a WebRequest object and have the page rendered but still stay in my function? I considered the HTML Agility Pack but don't believe it's any good for my purposes because that won't render the scripting.

Answer (score 0):

in the spirt of ignoring the question :-)  you should be able to use webbrowser control without loosing you place

see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/50544/Using-the-WebBrowser-Control-in-ASP-NET#funct